# Java - Trouble creating caves in tile based game

Tags: java, dictionary, generator, tile

I am trying to add caves to my tile based game but am having issues with the tiles not using the image when they are created.

Here is my code:

```
                    w = rand(10);
                    for (int wi = 0; wi <= w; wi++) {
                        h = rand(10);
                        for (int hi = 0; hi <= h; hi++) {
                            if (i - w >= 1 && j - h >= 1) {
                                map[i - w][j - h] = new tile(
                                        tiles.yellow, i * size, j
                                                * size, false);
                                if (h != 0) {
                                    h--;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (w != 0) {
                            w--;
                        }
                    }
```

Integer i is equal to the X coordinate of the tile.

Integer j is equal to the Y coordinate of the tile.

Here is the result of this:
[image]

What I was hoping for was for the grey areas to hold the tiles which are yellow and for the yellow tiles to not show up anywhere else. (I am only using this tile for testing)

If you know how I can correct this then please reply!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm completely confused by your code, but should not it be

```
map[i - w][j - h] = new tile(tiles.yellow, (i - w) * size, (j - h) * size, false);
```

Otherwise I'm completely at loss what you are trying to do here?

Comment: That actually sorted it out for me haha I was changing the data of a tile then adding the image over the original tile.

I really struggled to explain what I am trying to do, I just hoped it was enough.